# How to divide hibernate sequence by table?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I use hibernate sequence but when I add a record for table "A" if I insert a new record for table "B". The ID will continue by the value of A??? Why?

Exp: I insert 10 records for A, ID is auto increment. Then next record of B will have ID = 11.

I use this for all Entity:

```java
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @Id
    private int id;
```

My application.properties

```java
spring.datasource.driver-class-name.1=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=info
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

[image: Hibernate_sequence table]

Comment: No, my id is primary key. Then it doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is clearly explained in the 2 comment to the question linked above.

Comment: postman returns this meassage:  ```"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement""```

Comment: I got it! thank you @AlanHay